# A way to access the defaullt sorting method from Data Tables in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add the default functionality for sorting information inside a Data table from Vuetify, but I couldn't make it appear.

Code Sandbox with some comments  : https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-wfhe9?file=/src/App.vue

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="data"
        class="elevation-1 mt-4"
        :items-per-page="5"
        hide-default-header
      >
        <template v-slot:header="{ header }">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th
                v-for="(h, index) in headers"
                class="text-subtitle-2"
                style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdc6d8"
                :key="index"
              >
                <v-tooltip bottom :key="h.value">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ sort }">
                    <span v-on="sort">{{ h.text }}</span>
                  </template>
                </v-tooltip>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </template>
        <template #item="{ item }">
          <tr>
            <td style="border: 0; height: 70px">
              {{ item.name }}
            </td>
            <td style="border: 0; height: 70px">
              {{ item.date }}
            </td>
            <td style="border: 0; height: 70px">
              {{ item.quantity }}
            </td>
            <td style="border: 0; height: 70px">
              {{ item.expirationDate }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Name",
          align: "start",
          value: "name",
        },
        {
          text: "Date",
          align: "start",
          value: "date",
        },
        {
          text: "Quantity",
          align: "start",
          value: "quantity",
        },
        {
          text: "Expiration",
          align: "start",
          value: "expirationDate",
        },
      ],
      currentProds: [
        {
          name: "Proc 1",
          date: "01/01/01",
          quantity: 123,
          expirationDate: "01/02/02",
        },
        {
          name: "Proc 1",
          date: "01/01/01",
          quantity: 123,
          expirationDate: "01/02/02",
        },
        {
          name: "Proc 1",
          date: "01/01/01",
          quantity: 123,
          expirationDate: "01/02/02",
        },
        {
          name: "Proc 1",
          date: "01/01/01",
          quantity: 123,
          expirationDate: "01/02/02",
        },
        {
          name: "Proc 1",
          date: "01/01/01",
          quantity: 123,
          expirationDate: "01/02/02",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Searching google I found code that apparently works but only in previous versions (i'm using the last one)

Why i'm doing the header again? Designer asked for a different `border bottom` so trying to do this I made the thead again using the slot.

I dont want to add a custom sort, just the default one.

Is there a way to do this in 2.4.3 verison of Vuetify?

Comment: Can you please add the headers array? Also, you mean sorting by clicking the column name or another way?

Comment: @LastM4N sure, i tried to replicate my issue in a code sandbox but couldn't make it work... It's something like the code I put in the publication now. Thanks for reply

Comment: @sgf_1 can you share sandbox?

Comment: Just add the headers,we don't need any sandbox

Comment: @DaniilLoban sure, https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-wfhe9?file=/src/App.vue I just want the header mantain the style that I put there, with the ability to sort like the default one by Vuetify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this example from docs, also pay attention to `dataSort` function, for correct sorting implementation:

```js
  const dataSort = ((a, b) =>  a.split('/').reverse().join('/') <=  b.split('/').reverse().join('/') ? -1: 1)


  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data () {
      return {
        currentProds: [
          {
            name: "Proc 1",
            date: "07/01/01",
            quantity: 3,
            expirationDate: "07/02/02",
          },
          {
            name: "Proc 2",
            date: "02/01/01",
            quantity: 2,
            expirationDate: "02/02/03",
          },
          {
            name: "Proc 3",
            date: "01/01/01",
            quantity: 1,
            expirationDate: "01/02/01",
          },
          {
            name: "Proc 4",
            date: "01/01/01",
            quantity: 5,
            expirationDate: "01/02/02",
          },
          {
            name: "Proc 5",
            date: "01/01/01",
            quantity: 4,
            expirationDate: "01/02/02",
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      headers () {
        return [
          {
            text: 'Name',
            align: 'start',
            value: 'name',
          },
          {
            text: 'Date',
            value: 'date',
            sort: dataSort   // <----- important!
          },
          { 
            text: 'Quantity',
            value: 'quantity',
          },
          { 
            text: 'Expiration Date',
            value: 'expirationDate',
            sort: dataSort,  // <----- important!
          },
        ]
      },
    },
  })
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Vuetify Calendar Event Drag&#39;n&#39;Drop</title>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.3/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4.3/dist/vuetify.min.css'>

<style>

.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr:not(:last-child)>td:last-child,
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr:not(:last-child)>td:not(.v-data-table__mobile-row),
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr:not(:last-child)>th:last-child,
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr:not(:last-child)>th:not(.v-data-table__mobile-row),
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>thead>tr:last-child>th
{
    border-bottom: 0
}
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>thead>tr:last-child>th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bdc6d8;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <div>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="currentProds"
          item-key="name"
        >
        </v-data-table>
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried this, but my problem is that I need to re-create the header because I need to style it in a different way. So if you look at the code, I put some v-slots inside the datatable. The designer asked for "border-bottom: 2px solid #bdc6d8" and the component has a scoped style tag. 

My workaround was to re-do the header and append the icon   with  

<template v-slot:activator="{ sort }"><span v-on="sort">{{ h.text }}</span></template> but the sort does not work anymore. Im looking for a way to put the sort in a v-slot, if that makes any sense

Comment: maybe better add some style?

Comment: I added styles to snippet

Comment: This works !! thank you very much ! I had to add ::v-deep to the selector, how did you get that specific selector ?

Comment: I found this with dev-tools when looked for border-bottom style